# Workaround for the limit of the number of missing indexes suggested by SQL Server's DMV

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, dmv

In production, each instance of SQL Server has over 250 databases (what we call 'OrgDb's). The project I'm currently working on, aims to send all the reported missing indexes by SQL Server's DMV to telemetry, in order to do some post analysis on how well the queries sent to these orgDbs are doing and possibly do some optimizations.

Sounds straightforward, right? The problem however, is that there is a [max limit of 500 for the number of missing indexes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345485(v=sql.105).aspx) that DMV can report in a single SQL Server whereas we expect around 20 missing indexes per OrgDb (~ 5000 in total).

Can anyone think of a workaround for this limit? One solution I initially thought of, was to delete the DMV's missing index tables:

```
sys.dm_db_missing_index_details
sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups
sys.dm_db_missing_index_group
```

after each update, but turns out those tables cannot be modified:

```
Error:Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
```

Comment: you'd better to ask on DBA site: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Opened a new question there:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134799/workaround-for-the-limit-of-the-number-of-missing-indexes-suggested-by-sql-serve